# Is it possible to read content of an IceBreak 'marker' in the program code?

Tags: rpgle, rpg

I'm using IceBreak to make HTML frontend for RPG programs.

There is a function called 'SetMarker' which takes the name of the marker and the value:

```
SetMarker('Demo':'Example');
```

This makes the value available for the HTML code:

```
<!--#tag="MyTag"-->
<p>This is a/an <%$ Demo %></p>
```

When called by RPG:

```
ResponseWriteTag('IceB.html':'MyTag');
```

My question is: **Is it possible to check the value of a specific 'marker'? Or if it has been set?** Some kind of 'GetMarker' method perhaps?

(I tried searching here and there, but 'marker' and 'icebreak' mostly gives completely unrelated stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having searched through the methods defined by IceBreak I conclude that there is no defined way of obtaining the value of a marker.

The only method other than "SetMarker" that even mentions markers is "ParseMarker" which "Render current markers into the response object".

The short answer: **No, it is not possible.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for an answer, maybe try posting this question on [RPG400-L](http://lists.midrange.com/listinfo/rpg400-l)